# For somebody that travels the same route over and over again, what are some ways to save on airfare?

Tags: cost-cutting, travel, airline

I am an Indian immigrant currently living in Canada. My family is in India. As part of this arrangement, I need to travel back and forth between Toronto and new Delhi fairly frequently. (~2 times/yr, more in case of an emergency)

For somebody that travels the same route over and over again, **what are some ways to save on airfare?** The average price for a round trip is ~1500 CAD on Air India.  I can book any airline. I can book up to 2 months in advance.

Comment: Do you have a choice of airlines? How far ahead can you book the regular flights?

Comment: Voted to close; don't think a listing of "how to save on non-financial product X..." is a good money-based discussion.

Comment: @sdg:  Ehhhh ... I disagree.  Specific ways to save money are on-topic for personal finance, I'd think?  That, and it's more about method than focusing on finding a deal on a specific product.  The latter, I'd agree, would likely be off-topic.

Comment: @mbhunter Yes as long as it's about the method, general approach, etc. and not a specific shopping question on where to buy.  See related meta question:  http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/48/general-advice-on-getting-good-prices

Comment: @mbhunter, et al - OK, I stand(sit) corrected.  Can I take back my close vote?

Comment: @sdg close votes expire over time so it will take care of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yapta.com](http://www.yapta.com/) will track flight prices, so you can know when a good time historically is to make a bunch of reservations.  Also, Air India has a frequent flier program so I hope you have signed up for it... you could get free flights once you get enough points (although I would probably use your points for upgrades to business class).

Answer (score 2):

I remember when humorist Dave Barry discussed some guy who invented the software that guaranteed that no two airline passengers ever paid the same fare.  As with much of Dave Barry's stuff, it has way too much truth in it.

Research when the best time frame to buy your tickets is.  It varies wildly with time of day, time of week, time of year, whether the plane is half-empty or not, which airline you're traveling on, etc.

Beyond that, if you can rack up frequent flier miles fast enough, you maybe can offset the cost of one of those trips.